# jQuery dynamic DOM elements are not posted in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dom

I have a button with id `btnGo` wrapped in a form with id `frmNewRequest`. When I tried to use

```
$('#frmNewRequest').on('click', '#btnGo', (function(e){
//do something
}));
```

it was not working but when I changed to

```
$('#btnGo').click(function(e){
//do something
});
```

it was working. What is the different between the two ?

I have a DOM dynamically generated upon the click of `btnGo`, but when posted to codeigniter's controller, the newly DOM elements are not posted. Anyone now what's the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First snippet of code tries to click on form. where there is not method to click on form element. So, it will not work.

Whereas the second snippet you are clicking on button and button have a property to click So, it will work for you.